# GWT: Is Java fully supported by the SDK?

Tags: java, gwt, jakarta-ee, java-ee-5, java-5

Iam searching for an official announcement for Java 1.5 and JEE5 support by Google's GWT (2.1).
I couldnt find any specs which parts of the Java language are officially supported by GWT.
Aint there any statements by Google? So is it possible that all parts of the Java language are supported and translateable in JavaScript? Couldnt imagine!
The only thing I found on the GWT website is: "The GWT SDK provides a core set of Java APIs and libraries.." but no further declarations...

Would appriciate some help from the "Stackis",
sry for my bad english ;)
Lars

Comment: You should have a look here : [Language Support](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsCompatibility.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The page [Coding Basics - Compatibility with the Java language and Libraries](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsCompatibility.html) should answer your questions.

If you want a breakdown of the java packages and methods that are supported, you can go see the [JRE Emulation reference](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/RefJreEmulation.html) page.

Comment: bit embarrassing I wasnt able to find this by myself as it is in the official docs! Thank you, thats what I was looking for ;)